# Including lilypond source code in a question, alongside a static image

Tags: discussion

I recently used a web implementation of lilypond to produce a score snippet on a question [here.](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/61658/how-do-i-go-about-naming-understanding-the-second-chord-in-corcovado)

I've been looking through the meta, and it seems that I am by no means the first person to think lilypond support on SE would be a great idea, but that, alas, this is incredibly difficult to implement.

Still though, I thought I might like to include my lilypond source code in the question itself, for a couple of reasons: In general, having the source directly in the question rather than relying on an external image host just seems better. But more specifically, it would allow other users to edit the score snippet I gave.  For example, if I made a typo (which I actually did), then another user could quite easily correct that.  Or alternatively, if I myself wanted to add to or modify the example I gave, if the source was included in the question it wouldn't rely on me being on the same computer, and having saved it somewhere.

So my question is, despite Lilypond not being natively supported by SE, is it still a good idea to include the source markup in the question.  And if so, how?

My first thought was to simply put it  in as a hidden comment, which only shows up when editing the source. I'm not sure this is possible though, as an HTML comment block (`<!--` and `-->`) doesn't work when the music snippet contains angle brackets.

Including the full source code in the question itself seems like overkill, as it would detract visually from the question and add unnecessary clutter.

I suppose something like the below, while still outsourcing the code to an external host, is still an improvement on just a static image.

[image]

<sup>source: http://lilybin.com/qaymce/1
 https://pastebin.com/zYmPJjYw</sup>

Do any of you have any opinions on what might be good standard practice for this.  It certainly seems to me that including the source used to produce a score within the question/answer itself is advantageous, but what's the best way to do that?

Comment: If you read https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2460/104 you will see why lilypond is not going to happen for us. The sheer size of the codebase, for one. If you want to add in your own linked web objects, that's fine, but an even better idea will be to use ABC - it is fully supported and has extensive guidance.

Comment: I do not think there's a way to include it in the post, for the reasons you mention.  Your links seem great to me.