# Can we have some beginners guide to ABC notation for new users, or at least a note when posting saying "SE supports ABC notation using this syntax:"

Tags: feature-request

I ask because the only reason I'm even aware it's possible to include embedded sheet music in a question without just embedding an image is because [I asked a question on meta about lilypond](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2830/including-lilypond-source-code-in-a-question-alongside-a-static-image): there's nothing in the site tour, nothing in the help section, and no box when posting a question that even indicates it's possible to do this, and so I doubt I'm alone in being surprised to find out about it after having used the site for a while already!

A link to either an internal or external guide to the basic syntax of ABC wouldn't go amiss either, but in the first place some sort of visible notice to even suggest it's possible sounds like a good idea to me!

Perhaps there actually is one, and I've missed it, in which case I do apologise, but then on the other hand that's probably an indication that it's not visible enough.

In fact, right now I'm about to post a question with sheet music examples and it's actually been a bit tricky to even find out how to do it, I've had to flick through posts on meta to find one that has an example.  I think we're presenting an unnecesessary barrier to entry here.

Comment: I think it'd be better to also add [meta-tag:abcjs] tag to this feature request to help the categorization. Meanwhile, [this comment on Feb 2017 by Andrew Leach](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/abcjs-integration-now-available#comment6076_2574) also requested a similar addition, but looks like it was on hold for the moment due to the limitation...

Comment: We do have an ok internal meta about how to use abcjs which can be found here https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2782/7222.I agree it should be more transparent that we have abcjs and jtab active on this site