# Should we ask to use Vextab for music notation?

Tags: discussion

I know that we've decided [we want Lilypond support on Music.SE](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/913/decision-request-lilypond-support-from-the-se-developers). I've found a competitor to Lilypond that looks like it already has some good JS libraries called [Vextab](http://www.vexflow.com/vextab/). Would Vextab be a good tool for us, or do we want to ask for Lilypond support in particular?

Vextab has an interactive tutorial you can use to see what kinds of features it has and how it works: http://www.vexflow.com/vextab/tutorial.html

Briefly, I think the pros of Vextab are that it already has an implementation that the SE devs might be able to easily work into the website. The biggest downside I can think of is that Lilypond is a better known and more feature-complete tool, and if we ask for Vextab, we might not get Lilypond later. Also, while it's open-source, its developer wants to be paid for commercial usages, so we'd have to ask the devs to spend some money for us.

Comment: I just want to note that I myself am not sure that Vextab would be a good fit for us. But I think it's worth bringing up.

Comment: As I've stated before, I think technical aspects should be second to the language preferred. If there are showstoppers for the preferred language, we'll have to look into other alternatives. I'm not aware of any Lilypond showstoppers.

Comment: Also, a format which you have to pay for is worse than the already suggested alternative, ABC. That is free and more well known than Vextab.